# What are the constituents of "distributions" in GANs?

Tags: deep-learning, gan

We have a distribution for the Generator and the Discriminator, and we minimize their divergence, but how do the inputs (say, images) constitute a probability distribution?  Or is the distribution simply the noise introduced to the inputs?

Comment: These are regularisation quantities rather than distributions.

Comment: Can you give a simple example?